# When the speaker's voice keeps connection and disconnecting on a phone call

Tags: word-request, idioms, expressions

I was wondering whether the bold phrase below sounds idiomatic in English. If not, please let me know whether there is any fixed phrase / expression to substitute for the that:

> A) Do you hear me? 
> B) Yes 
> A) But this is a bad connection I think. You keep **connection and disconnecting**! Let me hang up and call you back. 
> B) Okay

Comment: You keep dropping out.

Answer (score 1):

You keep dropping out.............The line keeps dropping out.

Comment: In Britain we often say 'You're breaking up' when someone's voice becomes fragmented and hard to understand on a mobile phone, Skype, Zoom, etc.

Comment: Well @Bruce Murray as Michael mentioned, I have come across the term "breaking up" too. I am wondering if it a matter of regional preference?

Comment: May I ask you for which dialect are you talking @Bruce Murray?